# Customize Windows 10 Secure Sign in

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to change the size and location of the "press ctrl alt del" message to a custom size and location, to make it easier for users to see?

This is part of the secure sign in option.

I am trying to make it similar to the windows 7 experience, so users are less confused.

Any GPO or reg tweek welcome. I'm not above coding my own with a little direction.

Comment: This isn't possible with any group policy or registry setting as far as I'm aware. Are users really so "confounded" that the message is in the corner rather than center screen?

Comment: While I don't have an answer and don't believe it's possible, this feature has been relegated to the trash bins of history, as it provides little, if any, additional security and serves only as an inconvenience to users.  There was a decent in-depth article written about this feature a year or two ago about whether it's still relevant or not that went into depth, but the synopsis was it's a worthless feature and shouldn't be utilized because users know if it's them logging in, can be simulated virtually (making it's use moot), among others.  If I can find the article again, I'll post a link,

Comment: I know. My users are not computer literate and have little or no English. I am trying to make transition to windows 10 less painful for them.

Comment: I wasn't implying one is wrong for using it, just that I know some users who still utilize it on the belief it bolsters security (I was one who believed it did until I read that article), so I mention it to people if the feature comes up.